# How to retain number formats when inserting data into an xlsx workbook via openxlsx writeData()

Tags: r, excel

I have a .xlsx file I'm using as a template.  It's filled with colors, borders, number formats, etc.  I simply want to populate this workbook with data from R.

I'm using the `xlsx` package which works great, except that it appears to overwrite the pre-existing cell formats.  For example, let's start by generating a template workbook:

```
#--------------------------------------------------
# Create a workbook with styling 
# (I'm not actually making my workbook via code. This is just to generate a reproducible example.)

library(xlsx)

## Create a new workbook
wb <- createWorkbook("Sample Workbook")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sample Worksheet") 
writeData(wb, sheet = "Sample Worksheet", data.frame(Dates = as.Date(c("2017-1-1", "2018-1-1"))))
addStyle(wb, sheet = "Sample Worksheet", createStyle(numFmt="mm/dd/yy"), rows = 2:3, cols = 1, gridExpand = TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb, "Sample Workbook.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This should create a workbook, "Sample Workbook.xlsx" which looks like

[image]

Now let's make new values and insert them into our template:

```
#--------------------------------------------------
# Insert data and retain cell styles

newdates <- data.frame(Dates = as.Date(c("2019-1-1", "2020-1-1")))
wb <- loadWorkbook("Sample Workbook.xlsx")
writeData(wb, sheet = "Sample Worksheet", newdates)
saveWorkbook(wb, "Sample Workbook Modified.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This inserts data, but notice it removes the date formats we set up above

[image]

How can I insert data and retain the formats in my template workbook?

Comment: Maybe have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935312/updating-excel-spreadsheet-figures-using-the-xlsx-package-in-r

Comment: Thanks @Johan, but I don't see how that solves my question.  Can you elaborate?